# System.Drawing image locked after using statement closed

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm doing a .Net Core 2.2. project and trying to replace a deprecated `WebImage` process with `System.Drawing`. I'm trying to do a resize and all of that's mostly ok. The problem is when I try to delete the full size image, it's locked:

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
string filePath = serverPath + "\\" + userId + ".png";
string filePathResized = serverPath + "\\" + userId + "_resized.png";

using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
//<-- not locked here
using (var image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(filePath))) //<-- locks here
{
    var width = image.Width;
    var height = image.Height;
    double ratio = height / (double)width;

    var resizedImage = new Bitmap(AvatarScreenWidth, (int)(AvatarScreenWidth * ratio));
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, AvatarScreenWidth, (int)(AvatarScreenWidth * ratio));

    }

    resizedImage.Save(filePathResized, ImageFormat.Png);
}   //<----- should be closed here?

if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);  //<--- fails here because of locked file
}

return Path.GetFileName(filePathResized);
```

To my understanding from other SO questions and answers, the file should unlock when the `using` statement is closed. The resized file is closed but the original file is locked until I stop the debugger.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually test it, but it seems you are not actually disposing the image you created with `Image.FromFile`. Your `using` block is using a copy of said image.

As a first try, do not make a copy, but use the one you got:

```
using (var image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
```

Comment: Brilliant! I killed hours on that...Wish I asked sooner. Thanks so much! It says I can't accept the answer yet, so I'll circle back around...